# Events not rendering on live site without compatibility mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have a project in ASP.NET (.NET 4) and live it throws away my events (`SelectedIndexChanged`)

My localhost uses an IIS 8.0 and the webserver is using IIS 6.0

I have this code in my markup:

`<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlUsers" EnableViewState="True" AutoPostBack="True" Style="width: 120px;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsers_SelectedIndexChanged" />`

And on `localhost` it renders as:

```
<select name="ctl00$cphPages$ddlUsers" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$cphPages$ddlUsers\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="cphPages_ddlUsers" style="width: 120px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="">-- Choose user --</option>
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="4">Test 4</option>
    <option value="5">Test 5</option>
    <option value="6">Test 6</option>
</select>
```

And on the production server it renders as:

```
<select name="ctl00$cphPages$ddlUsers" id="cphPages_ddlUsers" style="width: 120px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="">-- Choose user --</option>
    <option value="1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="4">Test 4</option>
    <option value="5">Test 5</option>
    <option value="6">Test 6</option>
</select>
```

And thus my problem is, it doesn't fire the event when I select something in the dropdown..
And if I set the width with the `Width`-property, it also vanishes.

Update: It works in Compatibility Mode, but not otherwise (In IE10)

Update #2: Live it's running at Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Are you using IIS express/ASP.Net dev server/IIS on your localhost? and what do you use in production?

Comment: IIS 7.5 or 8.0 (I think, it's Win8, cannot find the version) on my localhost. And I guess it's IIS 6.0 on the server. But many of the other events works without problem. It's just this single page (I have even recreated it from scratch and got the same problem)

Comment: seems like same problem here : http://serverfault.com/questions/387796/controls-not-autopostbacking

Comment: It seems like his control at least reloads the page, this control just acts as a regular `select`-control.